# whats meaning of "Error establishing a database connection"

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, phpmyadmin

i have one wordpress blog name as

http://shareprogrammingtips.com/

its hosted on hostgator and works fine. But suddendly i am getting error like

Database Error:

```
Error establishing a database connection
```

when i open my blog.

i have not done anything with php my admin of my webspace. i havent touch any setting still i am getting this.

why this error comes and how can i remove that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have't changed anything in the site wp-config.php or in Wordpress at all, it's probably nothing more than a temporary glitch at your webhost. Open a ticket with them.

Comment: thanks somebody has changed my password in wp-config.php file so that problem was came. now i have solved that

Comment: Glad that worked. But if someone has unauthorized access to your site and FTP account, I'd change all your passwords.

Comment: that was done by mistakes by my friend..!!! nywz you pointed wp-config.php and i checked that and got solution

Answer (score 2):

Chances are there is an issue with one of the following:

- The database server is down (try connecting via a MySQL client such as PHPMyAdmin or the MySQL admin tools http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/gui-tools/5.0.html)
- Incorrect username/password
- Your username/password is correct however you don't have permission to connect from your current hostname (e.g. database only allows local connections).
- You specified a database table that does not exist.

Comment: but it was working fine i havnt did anything. I am a c programmer i dont know much about this stuff..

Comment: Try connecting to the MySQL database with another client, e.g. PHPMyAdmin. It's possible that the database server is down.

Comment: Have you received any email from HostGator recently? Sometimes hosting providers change their configuration (because of a possible security threat, for example) and things will start to break. A good hoster will always notify you in advance of such changes. Also HostGator offers a control panel (cPanel), you might try to login and see if the database server is running. Possibly you can reach phpMyAdmin from there.

Answer (score 0):

Hostgator places a limit that database can consume only 25% of total memory assigned to a hosting account. You have mysql server going away that crashed your server.Kind of "Memory Issues" if it is repeatedly occuring the hostgator support will finally ask you to upgrade